# Simple Post Request with file and parameters

Tags: c#, .net-4.6.1

I have this code, to make a post request to a Local Courier API.

```
public async Task ImportAwbIntegrat()
        {


            string fisier = File.ReadAllText(@"F:\Read\model.csv");

            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "username", "clienttest" },
                { "client_id", "70321588" },
                {"user_pass", "testing" },
                {"fisier", fisier }
            };


            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            try
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                string methodurl = "https://www.selfawb.ro/import_awb_integrat.php";

                var response = await client.PostAsync(methodurl, content);
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(message); ;
            }
        }
```

The request it`s working,

```
response value = {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://www.selfawb.ro/import_awb_integrat.php', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 442
}}
```

but inside the `responseString` i have this message:
"The file was not uploaded. It asks you, try again."

I think this happens because the server want a .csv file with value separated by ; but i send it the values from file, not the file itself.

Comment: You think or is that the actual case? Does your API require a .csv file? You should review the docs for the API and then accordingly design your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
public async Task ImportAwbIntegrat()
{
    string fisier = File.ReadAllText(@"F:\Read\model.csv");

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "username", "clienttest" },
        { "client_id", "111111" },
        {"user_pass", "testing" }
    };          

    var image = File.ReadAllBytes(@"F:\Read\model.csv");

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content =
            new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(image)), "fisier", "model.csv");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in values)
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(param.Value), $"\"{param.Key}\"");
            }

            using (var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.selfawb.ro/import_awb_integrat.php", content))
            {
                var input = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```